# putting two lists of different objects and sort them by date, objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

List 1 contains a list of object As and list 2 contains a list of object Bs.

Object A contains

```
date
quantity
message
```

Object B contains

```
date
email
first name
last name
```

Both object As and Bs has a property date in common. Are there anyway to merge them into one list and sorted by date.

Comment: Yes, there are several ways.  What have you tried?  Have you examined the various `sort...` methods of NSArray in the spec?

Comment: I'm not familiar with objective-c, but if it was in Java, I would probably have a super class C with the date field, then have Class A and B extend from C, and create a Comparator to compare objects of type C to sort them by the date field. Hope it helps.

Comment: @HotLicks : I am working on that and my issue is because they are 2 different kind of objects and how we can put them together in one list.

Comment: They're both NSObjects.  Both can be put into an NSArray or any other object that accepts NSObjects.  You can then tell them apart with `isKindOfClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should merge them into one Array (NSArray's arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:, right?)
and then you could use NSArray's sortedArrayUsingComparator:

```
    NSArray *mergedArray = [array1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array2];

    NSArray *orderedArray = [mergedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate *date1 = [obj1 date];
        NSDate *date2 = [obj2 date];
        return [date1 compare:date2];
    }];
```

I haven't tested the code, but it's going to be something like that.

Comment: @bruno koga : learn something new today. thanks. I will get back and let you know about this.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *listA = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objA0, objA1, objA2, nil];
NSArray *listB = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objB0, objB1, objB2, nil];

NSMutableArray *allObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:listA];
[allObjects addObjectsFromArray:listB];

[allObjects sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(id obj1, id obj2){
    NSDate *date1 = obj1.date;
    NSDate *date2 = obj2.date;
    return [date1 compare:date2]; }];
```

Comment: @dang : thanks, iam working on that and let you know as well.